# Invalid cast error message while returning datetime field from datareader

Tags: c#

I have a property declared in a model like this

```
public DateTime DelDate { get; set; }
```

I am reading a datetime field from the database and storing in 
DelDate below

```
DelDate = reader.GetDateTime(reader.Getordinal("delivdate"))
```

I kept getting the error message below

"specified cast is not valid"

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Are there any nulls in that column? You're supposed to call IsDBNull befor calling GetDateTime

Answer (score 1):

Check if your column value is not a `null` value, for sample:

```
int delivDateIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("delivdate");

DelDate = reader.IsDBNull(delivDateIndex) ? 
                          DateTime.Now : // a default value
                          reader.GetDateTime(delivDateIndex); // original value
```

If the column accept null, change your model to `DateTime?` and try this:

```
DelDate = reader[reader.GetOrdinal("delivdate")] as DateTime?;
```